# Centering a picture inside a circle

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a border around an image but whatever I do, I can’t position the image in the center of the circle. I will really appreciate if you can help to solve this. Here is my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWzmdZ).

```css
.firstcell::after {
  border: 2px solid rgba(138, 223, 199, 0.74);
  border-radius: 500%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

.firstcell.status_1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Some Title</h1>
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstcell status_1"></td>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Title1</td>
        <td><a href="#">Link1</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstcell status_1"></td>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>Title2</td>
        <td><a href="#">Link2</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you put the background image in `.firstcell::after`?

Comment: It is almost **never** a good idea to use `position: absolute;` in a `table`.

Comment: @user500665 I will have multiple status values. Therefore I want to add circle for all `firstcell` class and add different image according to `status`

Comment: Depending on the images you will probably have to find the ideal background-position for each image individually.

Comment: Just put the background in `.firstcell.status_1:after` and use background-position:center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` from your pseudo element, add `display: block;`, then apply a `background-position` to the `background-image`.

```css
.firstcell::after {
  border: 2px solid rgba(138, 223, 199, 0.74);
  border-radius: 500%;
  content: "";
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  display: block;
}

.firstcell.status_1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAXZJREFUSA1jYBgFoyFAaQgwggz4uzDwPzkG/f7/X4UjYcNdfHqZ8ElSQ47mFlAUROGS/Qe+MXLwwHzKyMhwZ6uLRBSQDw9yinzwk4ldA2jWGUZGxsr///9V/2dgNPXa9TIdZiGIpsgCiEGMt7a6iO/Z7ia1i/Hv33BGpv/NTpsfS8MsYYExyKWBYczlvOeJMEj/D4Z/Dzj+MU7n5GCdBuT6g8Qo9wEjYwsHA+sbGGZgYqplYGT089750oo6FoBMwQL+M//lAwlj8cF/UAr4jkUPfqH//7+hKPjPwA3io1gATAlv2BI3vmGOX885Y++99Sga8HCOFfju3OoqwXU4230JMIH+BSllZGSeD6LBkfzvP0MPiJO54ALn33//U4HM3OxFFyenOSmBxUFy2ADnvx9/nz24z/v+yqksoLzxp5sXzn64c7mNX0WHE2jRD2x6mIGCP4EYFEwo6RmbYiSxO1A9F5DEcDJBlqjjlMUtYYJbalRmIEMAAKGecc1FS0saAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
  background-position: 40% 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Some Title</h1>
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstcell status_1"></td>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td>Title1</td>
        <td><a href="#">Link1</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="firstcell status_1"></td>
        <td>Name2</td>
        <td>Title2</td>
        <td><a href="#">Link2</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go! Avoid using CSS linked images (only for static backgrounds).
If you want a line around the image, just add border attribute.

```css
img {
border-radius:50%;
background-color:red;
border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/tq3WqEUxtRyBn-d_0t3j6WKNHuJDrmLq-FE3GAYrsAMQFIaS7FIgRLfzzql2SvfvLqto=w300">
```

Comment: I am trying to draw a empty circle with 2px border. Look my sample. This is not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Mate, as I said, just add border attribute and avoid using CSS linked images. We are not going to code it for you, just show you the right way how you do it.